# How do you organize an SQL database depending on a specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database holding a few columns ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'). I want to echo the table in descending order according to 'd', an integer.

For example, the existing table:

```
+------------+---------+-------------+----+
|     A      |    B    |      C      | D  |
+------------+---------+-------------+----+
| Lorem      | Ipsum   | Dolor       |  7 |
| Sit        | Amet    | Consectetur |  4 |
| Adipiscing | Elit    | Sed         | 13 |
| Do         | Eiusmod | Tempor      |  1 |
| Incididunt | Ut      | Labore      |  6 |
+------------+---------+-------------+----+
```

What should be outputted:

```
+------------+---------+-------------+----+
|     A      |    B    |      C      | D  |
+------------+---------+-------------+----+
| Adipiscing | Elit    | Sed         | 13 |
| Lorem      | Ipsum   | Dolor       |  7 |
| Incididunt | Ut      | Labore      |  6 |
| Sit        | Amet    | Consectetur |  4 |
| Do         | Eiusmod | Tempor      |  1 |
+------------+---------+-------------+----+
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Hint:  `order by d desc`.

Comment: Figure out which column (`a`, `b`, `c` or `d`) holds the amount and add it to your `ORDER BY` clause. Don't forget to add `d` to undo ties.

Comment: Your data appears to be in one column only.  Even in this case, we can just use `ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1) DESC` to get the result you want.

Comment: @Eric I'm learning SQL. This database holds filler content so I can learn.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There are 4 word separated by 3 spaces, maybe is just a formating issue. But yes is confusing and OP should edit the data to a more tabular format. Try this site. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: Tyler I try to fix your data format, you can rollback if isnt the right interpretation.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM table 
ORDER BY d DESC;
```